# set text color of Appcompat action bar does not work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

Basically I followed this guide about customizing the Action bar https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

and have this style in my styles.xml

```
    <style name="Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_blue</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

with this custom action bar to change title text to white

```
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubtitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar subtitle text -->
<style name="MyActionBarSubtitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

but apparently the text and icon color remains black. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you remove all the styling except the `colorPrimary`/`colorPrimaryDark`/`colorAccent`? The default should be white text on a dark background when using `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: Also note that AppCompat v21 no longer ever uses the `android:` prefixed attributes so those can be removed entirely in any case.

Comment: you are right, I remove the `android:` prefix and it still works. The problem now is, the text color changes but it somehow overrides the `colorPrimary` of the action bar, so with `Theme.AppCompat.Light` I get a gray action bar background with changed title text color.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I just removed all the text style and set the parent theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and now it works perfectly (I just want to change the text to white). Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the text to be white, that is the default for `Theme.AppCompat` or, if you want a light activity, use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: What about a custom color? actionMenuTextColor is not working anymore